# how to change the Photo Access permission message(objective c)

Tags: objective-c, ios10, info-plist

i have tried changing the description using infoplist.strings, but how can i replace the project name with the new one in the title of the alert view. can anyone guide me

[i want to replace ABCDE with my app title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNQzP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the display name of your app. You can't just change it for this alert.

If you wan't to change the display name of your app (The one appears on the home screen). You can do that by changing the value of *Bundle Name* `CFBundleName` in your `Info.plist`.